# cross-browser solution for changing content of last li element

Tags: jquery

I have following un-ordered list structure

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I need to replace Milk with Buttermilk, How can I do it, using jQuery ofcourse?
I need solution, which works on every browser, starting with IE7+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector

```
$('li').filter(':last').text('Buttermilk')
```

Comment: Is there a reason (other than personal preference) that you don't collapse the selector into the first part (`$('li:last').text('Buttermilk')`)

Comment: It's in the documentation: "To achieve the best performance when using :last to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":last")"

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul li:last").html("Buttermilk");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li:last').html('Buttermilk');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/3duZK/

**From the jQuery api documentation:**

`:last` selects a single element by filtering the current jQuery collection and matching the last element within it.

When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').find('li:last').html('Buttermilk');
```